# Toggling multiple divs and also close when anywhere outside the div is clicked

Tags: jquery, toggle

I use this jQuery code to toggle a div and also make the div to close if anywhere outside the div is clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('html').click(function(){
  $('div').hide();
});

$('a').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$('div').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$('a').click(function(){
  $('div').toggle();
});

})
```

But I have many divs which I need to run this function so I did this:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="tgl" id="link-1" alt="div-1">LINK 1</a>
<a href="javascript:;" class="tgl" id="link-2" alt="div-2">LINK 2</a>
<a href="javascript:;" class="tgl" id="link-3" alt="div-3">LINK 3</a>
<div id="div-1"></div>
<div id="div-2"></div>
<div id="div-3"></div>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('html').click(function(){
  $('#div-1').hide();
  $('#div-2').hide();
  $('#div-3').hide();
});

$('#link-1').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$('#link-2').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$('#link-3').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$('#div-1').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$('#div-2').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$('#div-3').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$('.tgl').click(function(){
  altDiv = $(this).attr('alt');
  $('#'+altDiv).toggle();
});

})
```

But it works for only the first div, the two other divs don't even toggle at all
here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/the_king/5amv76uz/) link. I want each `link` `toggle` the `div` `id` with the `alt` value. which means that if `div-1` is toggled on and `link-2` is clicked, the `div-1` will be hidden and `div-2` will show up

Comment: It's working https://jsfiddle.net/5amv76uz/2/

Comment: You forgot to include jQuery in your fiddle

Comment: but I want only a div to be visible

Comment: I have posted a working jsFiddle in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To shorten your code also you should use this

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="tgl" id="link-1" alt="div-1">LINK 1</a>
<a href="javascript:;" class="tgl" id="link-2" alt="div-2">LINK 2</a>
<a href="javascript:;" class="tgl" id="link-3" alt="div-3">LINK 3</a>
<div class="divClass" id="div-1"></div>
<div class="divClass" id="div-2"></div>
<div class="divClass" id="div-3"></div>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('html').click(function(){
        $('#div-1').hide();
        $('#div-2').hide();
        $('#div-3').hide();
    });

    $('.divClass').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $('.tgl').click(function(e){
        altDiv = $(this).attr('alt');
        $('#'+altDiv).toggle();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

})
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that not all your code was inside `$(document).ready(function() {});`. Please see this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ukaoqvv/3/) which will show that the `altDiv` is getting the correct name and is being displayed. You can see that on inital load the `div`'s are hidden and are displayed when the corresponding links are clicked.

I have also reformatted your code so is more readable and removes repeatable code.

Also, I have removed `$('html').click()` as it is not required for what you are trying to achieve